# Strange php redirections with nginx (Works fine in apache)

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, php, redirect

Finally I decide to ask here after hours trying, searching and researching.

Months ago I migrated my site to a newer version and everything works fine with my old hosting in apache.

Recently I migrate to a VPS where I decide to use Nginx as server and I'm working in the details.

My problem is that I'm trying to make some specific redirections using a PHP script.

The redirections works pretty well in apache (locally and remotelly) but in nginx does not.

The strange behavior is that for example when I try to use the URL fakesite.tk/Section/index.php apache redirect to fakesite.tk/Section/ but Nginx returns a 404 error and if I try the URL fakesite.tk/Section/index.php/ mysteriously work (note the slash at the end) and redirect to fakesite.tk/Section// (Note the double slash)

I tryed to add a slash to the end of all URLS but this redirection equally don't work in Nginx.

If it matters, my VPS runing in Ubuntu (iquals that my host) and I make tests in a Windows machine.

There are my Nginx site config file:

```
server
{
         server_name *.fakesite.tk;
         return 301 $scheme://www.fakesite.tk$request_uri;
}

#Redirect non www to www site version
server
{
         server_name fakesite.tk;
         return 301 $scheme://www.fakesite.tk$request_uri;

}

server
{
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        root /var/www/SiteFolder;
        index index.php;

        server_name www.fakesite.tk;

        #Stabilishing error 404 and 403 error pages
        error_page 404 /?error=404;
        error_page 403 /?error=403;

        #Friendly URLs
        location /
        {
        location /
        {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
                rewrite ^/([^/]*)/$ /?sect=$1 last;
                rewrite ^/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ /?sect=$1&lang=$2 last;
                rewrite ^/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ /?sect=$1&lang=$2&cont=$3 last;
                rewrite ^/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ /?sect=$1&lang=$2&cont=$3&subcont=$4 last;
        }

        #Adding expire header
        location ~* \.(?:ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png|eot|svg|ttf|woff)$
        {
                expires 30d;
                add_header Pragma public;
                add_header Cache-Control "public";
        }

        #Enabling PHP
        location ~ \.php$
        {
                # With php5-fpm:
                try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
#                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }

        #deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one

        location ~ /\.ht
        {
                deny all;
        }
}
```

And my php redirection script:

```
<?php 
    ini_set('display_errors', true);//Si estamos en local se muestran con normalidad los errores.
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    $url = "http://$_SERVER[SERVER_NAME]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
    $newurl = $url;

    $newurl = str_replace('_', '-', $url);//Reeplace all _ with -


    $newurl = str_replace('index.php', '', $newurl);//Removing a index.php

    $newurl = str_replace('.php', '', $newurl);//Removing all .php

    $newurl = str_replace('/Intro', '', $newurl);//Removing all intro sections

    $extens = preg_match('/\.(jpg|gif|png|jpeg|js|css|woff|html|eot|svg|ttf|xml|map|min|txt)/', $newurl);

    if($extens !== 1 && $newurl[strlen($newurl) - 1] !== '/') //Trying to put a slash at the end
    {
        $newurl.='/';
    }

    if($url !== $newurl)
    {
        header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
        header("Location: $newurl");
    }
?>
```

I suppose that maybe is very small detail that I even not see, so I appreciate your help. Many thanks.

EDIT: I verified that the var $newurl effectively  changed and goes inside the if condition, but the `header(....);` lines does not executed, I put an `exit();` command after that and it is being executed, it means that affectively the `header(...);` lines not been executed.

EDIT 2: When I put manually a underscore in the URL and slash at the end of it, this redirects pretty good but if I don´t put a slash at the end it does not work even when run the conditional block.

Comment: Did you inspect the logs?

Comment: Of course @utrecht the logs look fine no error there. In fact I finally solved it, I will post the solution in few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys. I finally solved it, just like I said was a very small detail (the small details are the most difficult always).

The problem was with the `fcgi` for PHP configured in the virtual host file for nginx.

In the original file (below) I said to `fcgi` that try find the file and if not trigger a `404 error`, this was my mistake because it trigger his self error and don't allow to my site to manage this, so the redirection script does not be executed.

```
#Enabling PHP
location ~ \.php$
{
    # With php5-fpm:
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

To solve the problem. I simply said to the `fcgi` that send the code error like a parameter to allow to the site manage it, just like this:

```
#Enabling PHP
location ~ \.php$
{
    # With php5-fpm:
    #try_files $uri =404; #Mistake here!!
    try_files $uri /?error=404;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

EDIT: I prefer to add the trailing slash at the end of the URL (to avoid 404 errors) using the proper nginx virtual host config file because PHP doesn't work properly. I only added the following line inside the `server` block: `#Adding trailing slash at the end rewrite ^([^.]*[^/])$ $1/ permanent;`

Notice that it only redirects when the URL have not a dot `'.'`.

I hope that someone could use this experience to solve a related problem, in the future.

See you then.